# How do I achieve this circular progress bar in flutter, using the stop button to both stop the timer and progress indicator

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

a ui design of a screen with circular progress indicator

```
TweenAnimationBuilder(
                      duration: const Duration(seconds: 30),
                      tween: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0),
                      builder: (context, value, _) => SizedBox(
                        height: 180,
                        width: 180,
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                          value: value,
                          color: const Color(0xff166922),
                          backgroundColor: const Color(0xffFFC500),
                          strokeWidth: 10,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onEnd: () {
                        _controller.repeat();
                      },  
                    ),
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what u want to achieve. Can you pls update your question? I also don't understand Is this code what you already tried and its not working? Pls Describe your problem, what you tried, what not work, what you want to archive exactly.

Comment: The circular progress indicator is supposed to "countdown" from 30 seconds along with the timer, but the button is supposed to be able to stop and reset it.

Answer (score 0):

________Update:
Well I see, my bad. I misunderstood.

Since you already defined a controller, you can do:

```
... 
/// Time can have any value here. You will update it anyways. Initialize it under your controller. And also create _isPlaying.
int time = 0
bool _isPlaying = true;
...
/// update your time in the builder so you can 
 builder: (context, value, _) {
          setState(() {
          /// Update Ur time, so you can repeat from this specific point
          time = value;
          });
             return SizedBox(
                        height: 180,
                        width: 180,
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                          value: value,
                          color: const Color(0xff166922),
                          backgroundColor: const Color(0xffFFC500),
                          strokeWidth: 10,
                        ),
                      );
         }
.............
void stopOrContinue(){
   if(_isPlaying){
      /// To stop animation
      _controller.stop();
      _isPlaying = !_isPlaying;
   }else{
      /// To start from a point other than the very beginning.
      _controller.forward(from: time);
   }
   /// To start from beginning
   ///_controller.forward();
}
```

___OLD Answer

```
/// Create your Time, which u will use as the circularProgressIndicator value. 
  int timeCounter = 30;
/// Create your timer, which will count down.
  late Timer timer;
/// Method to start your timer. It will automatically stop if timeCounter is 0.
  void updateExecutionTime() {
    timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {
/// Here you will countdown the time and it will update your Indicator.
        timeCounter--;
      });

      if (timeCounter == 0) {
        timer.cancel();
      }
    });
  }

/// Method to stop your timer
void stopTimer() {
  timer.cancel();
}
```

Please be careful. This is code can create errors. Like:

- you have to cancel timer when you close the page, if its still running
- when you want to stop the timer and it is not initialized yet!

But all in all this should work for you.

Comment: Thank you, but what I am asking for is the circular progress indicator. How to pause it and continue it.

Comment: There you go, this should work

Comment: Thank you so much, I found a solution that worked.